# Передача данных из одной переменной/lineEdit/textView одного класса в другую переменную другого класса

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, pyside2

**front класса MessageWindow**:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_message_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, message_window):
        message_window.setObjectName("message_window")
        message_window.resize(506, 286)
        message_window.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(506, 236))
        message_window.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(506, 286))
        self.line_title = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(message_window)
        self.line_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 411, 31))
        self.line_title.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.line_title.setFont(font)
        self.line_title.setObjectName("line_title")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(message_window)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.window_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(message_window)
        self.window_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 491, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.window_text.setFont(font)
        self.window_text.setObjectName("window_text")
        self.button_confirm = QtWidgets.QPushButton(message_window)
        self.button_confirm.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 491, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button_confirm.setFont(font)
        self.button_confirm.setObjectName("button_confirm")

        self.retranslateUi(message_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(message_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, message_window):
        message_window.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("message_window", "Form", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("message_window", "Title", None, -1))
        self.button_confirm.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("message_window", "Confirm", None, -1))
```

**front класса Main**:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_NoteList(object):
    def setupUi(self, NoteList):
        NoteList.setObjectName("NoteList")
        NoteList.resize(560, 645)
        NoteList.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(560, 645))
        NoteList.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(560, 645))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(NoteList)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 171, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.line_login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_login.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.line_login.setFont(font)
        self.line_login.setObjectName("line_login")
        self.line_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 50, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.line_password.setFont(font)
        self.line_password.setObjectName("line_password")
        self.button_log = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 10, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.button_log.setFont(font)
        self.button_log.setObjectName("button_log")
        self.button_sign = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_sign.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 50, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.button_sign.setFont(font)
        self.button_sign.setObjectName("button_sign")
        self.button_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_add.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.button_add.setFont(font)
        self.button_add.setObjectName("button_add")
        self.button_delete = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_delete.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.button_delete.setFont(font)
        self.button_delete.setObjectName("button_delete")
        self.button_edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 90, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.button_edit.setFont(font)
        self.button_edit.setObjectName("button_edit")
        self.table_w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_w.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 541, 491))
        self.table_w.setObjectName("table_w")
        self.table_w.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_w.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_w.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_w.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table_w.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        NoteList.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(NoteList)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        NoteList.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(NoteList)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NoteList)

    def retranslateUi(self, NoteList):
        NoteList.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "LOGIN", None, -1))
        self.label_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "PASSWORD", None, -1))
        self.button_log.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "LOG IN", None, -1))
        self.button_sign.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "SIGN UP", None, -1))
        self.button_add.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "ADD", None, -1))
        self.button_delete.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "DELETE", None, -1))
        self.button_edit.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "EDIT", None, -1))
        self.table_w.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "Date", None, -1))
        self.table_w.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "Title", None, -1))
        self.table_w.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("NoteList", "Text", None, -1))
```

**main.py**:

```py
from frontend import *
from front_reg import Ui_reg_window
from message_window import Ui_message_window
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

import sys


class MessageWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_message_window):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent

        self.button_confirm.clicked.connect(self.buttonConfirm)

    def buttonConfirm(self):
        self.parent.title = self.line_title.text()
        self.parent.text = self.window_text.toPlainText()


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_NoteList):

    LOGGED = False

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # try:
        #     tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
        #     self.root = tree.getroot()
        # except:
        #     with open('data.xml'):
        #         root = ET.Element('datalist')
        #         tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        #         tree.write('data.xml')
        #         self.root = ET.parse('data.xml').getroot()

        self.table_w.setRowCount(15)
        self.table_w.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_w.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        # Установите ширину нужного вам столбца
        self.table_w.setColumnWidth(0, 70)
        self.table_w.setColumnWidth(1, 100)

        # Это свойство содержит политику переноса текста в элементе
        self.table_w.setWordWrap(False)

        # self.table_w.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        # self.table_w.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("12.12.3012"))
        # self.table_w.setItem(0, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Редактирование невозможно."))

        self.table_w.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(33)
        self.table_w.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.line_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.line_password.setMaxLength(13)

        self.button_log.clicked.connect(self.buttonLog)
        self.button_sign.clicked.connect(self.buttonReg)
        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)

    # def buttonLog(self):
    #     self.login = self.line_login.text()
    #     self.password = self.line_password.text()
    #     for person in self.root.iter('person'):
    #         if self.login not in [person.attrib['login'] for person in self.root.iter('person')]:
    #             message = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    #             message.setWindowTitle('Bad')
    #             message.setText('Wrong login')
    #             message.setIcon(message.Warning)
    #             message.exec()
    #             break
    #         if person.attrib['login'] == self.login and person.attrib['password'] == self.password:
    #             message = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    #             message.setWindowTitle('Good')
    #             message.setText('Log In Successful')
    #             message.setIcon(message.Information)
    #             message.exec()
    #             self.LOGGED = True
    #             break

    # def buttonReg(self):
    #     self.window = RegWindow()
    #     self.window.show()
    #     # print(self.window.login, self.window.password)

    def buttonAdd(self):
        self.win = MessageWindow()
        self.win.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Суть**: при нажатии <kbd>ADD</kbd> открывается окно, в котором можно ввести заголовок и текст заметки.

**Что мне хотелось бы получить**: чтобы при нажатии <kbd>Confirm</kbd> в открывшемся окне класса **MessageWindow**, вызванного из *класса Main*, в этот *класс Main* в переменную записался текст из двух окон **класса MessageWindow**, а именно

```
self.title = lineEdit из MessageWindow

self.text = textView из MessageWindow
```

То есть когда пользователь введет заметку и нажмет подтвердить, тайтл и текст заметки сохранились в классе `Main` для дальнейшей работы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MessageWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget): #, Ui_message_window):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageWindow, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent                                           # ! parent
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)       # ! Qt.Window
        self.setWindowTitle("MessageWindow")

        self.line_title = QLineEdit()
        self.window_text = QTextEdit()

        self.button_confirm = QPushButton("button_confirm")
        self.button_confirm.clicked.connect(self.buttonConfirm)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_title)  
        layout.addWidget(self.window_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_confirm)

    def buttonConfirm(self):
#        self.title = self.line_title.text()
#        self.text = self.window_text.toPlainText()

        self.parent.lineEdit.setText(self.line_title.text())             # +++
        self.parent.textEdit.setText(self.window_text.toPlainText())     # +++
        self.hide()                                                      # +++


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, Ui_NoteList):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()

        self.button = QPushButton("button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)   

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)  
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)


    def buttonAdd(self):
        self.win = MessageWindow(self)                                   # ! self
        self.win.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = Main()
    w.setWindowTitle("Main")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> а как можно получить к этим данным доступ из Main?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MessageWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageWindow, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent                                           
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)       
        self.setWindowTitle("MessageWindow")

        self.line_title = QLineEdit()
        self.window_text = QTextEdit()

        self.button_confirm = QPushButton("button_confirm")
        self.button_confirm.clicked.connect(self.buttonConfirm)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_title)  
        layout.addWidget(self.window_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_confirm)

    def buttonConfirm(self):
        self.parent.lineEdit.setText(self.line_title.text())             
        self.parent.textEdit.setText(self.window_text.toPlainText())     
        self.hide()                                                      


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, Ui_NoteList):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()

        self.button = QPushButton("button") 
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)  
        self.button2 = QPushButton("button2") 
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd2) 

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)  
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

    def buttonAdd(self):
        self.win = MessageWindow(self)                                   
        self.win.show()

    def buttonAdd2(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.win.line_title.text())             # +++
        self.textEdit.setText(self.win.window_text.toPlainText())     # +++   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = Main()
    w.setWindowTitle("Main")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> изменил суть самого вопроса ...

Суть вопроса никак не изменилась. Вам нужно инициализировать переменные `self.title` и `self.text` в классе `Main`

Вам надо понять, что виджет без родителя - это окно. Но так как вам надо переопределять значения переменных родительского виджета в дочернем, вам надо передать родителя `self.win = MessageWindow(self)`, но чтобы виджет остался окном надо включить флаг `Qt.Window`.

```
. . .
class MessageWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_message_window):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MessageWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)        # +

        self.button_confirm.clicked.connect(self.buttonConfirm)

    def buttonConfirm(self):
        self.parent.title = self.line_title.text()
        self.parent.text = self.window_text.toPlainText()
        self.hide()                                                     # +


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_NoteList):
    LOGGED = False
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.title = ''                                                 # +
        self.text = ''                                                  # +
        self.button_edit.clicked.connect(self.onClickedEdit)            # +

        self.table_w.setRowCount(15)
        self.table_w.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_w.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        # Установите ширину нужного вам столбца
        self.table_w.setColumnWidth(0, 70)
        self.table_w.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        # Это свойство содержит политику переноса текста в элементе
        self.table_w.setWordWrap(False)
        self.table_w.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(33)
        self.table_w.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.line_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.line_password.setMaxLength(13)
        self.button_add.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)

    def buttonAdd(self):
        self.win = MessageWindow(self)                                  # + self
        self.win.show()


    def onClickedEdit(self):                                            # +
        self.label.setText(self.title)
        self.label_2.setText(self.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как можно получить к этим данным доступ из Main?

Comment: я видимо не корректно сформулировал вопрос, данные из этих ячеек надо перенести в переменную, ибо в Main нет таких же окон(lineEdit и textView там отсутствуют)

Comment: `self.parent.lineEdit` в классе `MessageWindow` - это и есть `self.lineEdit` в классе `Main`, но я добавил решение, которое может выдернуть данные из дочернего класса.

Comment: в общем, если сначала и по полкам - в предыдущем вопросе я спрашивал про таблицу, данные в нее я хочу передать из окошка другого класса, которое я вызываю кнопкой из Main, то есть я хочу после написания текста в эти полоски, этот текст переходил в 2 переменные класса Main

Comment: с вашего позволения я изменю вопрос

Comment: изменил суть самого вопроса, если не сложно, посмотрите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!!

Comment: @finally я добавил очередное обновление, но там ничего нового.

Comment: а Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint Qt тут откуда? в импортах его нет, среда ругается говорит на знает таких

Comment: закоментил эту строку, это не совсем то) LOGIN и PASSWORD это лэйблы да, но это не self.title и не self.text, это просто поля, говорящие что рядом с ними надо ввести пароль(у меня есть система авторизации но она не касается вопроса), а текст Привет и Мир из вашего примера мне надо записать в обычные переменные, прям как a = 3, b = '123', только self.title = данные из lineEdit, self.textt = данные из textEdit

Comment: прошу прощения что так гружу, но по факту это обычный обмен данных из одного класса в другой, только я не пойму как это сделать((

Comment: Вам надо понять, что виджет без родителя - это окно. Но так как вам надо переопределять значения переменных родительского виджета в дочернем, вам надо передать родителя `self.win = MessageWindow(self)`, но чтобы виджет остался окном надо включить флаг `Qt.Window`.

Comment: @finally  https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=setwindowflags#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setWindowFlags   The END !

Comment: даже разобравшись со флагами, все равно не могу понять как передать текст из self.parent.title = self.line_title.text()  в простую переменную в коде в классе Main...

Comment: не в лэйбл, ни куда либо, а просто в переменную

Comment: @finally после нажатия на кнопку `Confirm` переменные `self.title` и `self.text` переопределены. Используйте их где вам надо. Я просто чтобы показать вам, что они уже есть с новыми значениями, добавил пункт `4` и присвоил лейбам их значения для визуализации.

Comment: вот теперь все стало на свои места, еще раз большое спасибо!